# Reality-based non-religious conservative news source?

Tags: conservatism

This would probably make more sense for liberal users: in order to see opposing points of view, what would be a "good" source of reality-driven (as opposed to stereotypes / prejudice / lies), non-religious conservative news / commentary?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18193/discussion-on-question-by-user44212-reality-based-non-religious-conservative-new).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: your best bet is blogs (for a variety of reasons I won't expand into). More often than not, more libertarianish bent than strictly conservative. Libertarians generally have non-religious viewpoint yet arrive to many of the same conclusions as conservatives from their own angles. Some sources:

- The granddaddy of them all: [Instapundit](http://pjmedia.com/instapundit/)

  Not really "consirvative" (not that someone as deeply biased and opinionated and liberally brainwashed as your question's wording implies would know the difference) but Instapundit is a link aggregator blog from mostly libertarian viewpoint.

  Upsides:

  - the blogger is a whip smart law professor, very well established in the niche and well respected.
  - reading a bit extensively (even opinion pieces linked) will give you good exposure on what non-liberal people are saying about the news.
  - The blog itself can be viewed as news summary, without actually reading linked pieces, often enough.

  Downsides: He doesn't actually bother classifying his links into "straight up news"/"opinion blog pieces" or "libertarian"/"conservative" etc... That exercise is left to the reader.
- I haven't actually consumed [Vodkapundit's blog](http://pjmedia.com/vodkapundit/) but seems to be popular and clearly distinguishes his own opinions from news he's commenting on.
- [Samizdata](http://www.samizdata.net/) is frequently content from non-US point of view (seems to be heavily UK based)

Comment: regarding "brainwashing", do yourself a favor and read http://mediamatters.org/blog/2010/12/17/umd-report-regular-viewers-of-fox-news-more-lik/174484 or http://www.desmogblog.com/fox-news-effect-few-references or http://publicmind.fdu.edu/2011/knowless/

Comment: ... and if you feel inclined to discount most sources as partisan, that too is specific to the conservative mindset: http://www.journalism.org/2014/10/21/political-polarization-media-habits/

Comment: @user44212 - no, not MOST sources. Just those where 90%+ of participants (a) vote Democrat and (b) deeply believe that influencing the public in the direction of their own politics is part of their job. Namely, most journalists (there are internal polls of journalist' politics. Look it up).

Comment: @user44212 - Also, given that there actually WERE links between Saddam and Islamist terrorists, I'm a lot less inclined to trust that study you linked than I would have if they didn't assume that the answer "yes" is indicative of being misinformed as opposed to not knowing minute differences between Al Quaeda and Abu Nidal (given that most MSNBC viewers probably don't even know who Abu Nidal was either).

Comment: Look at the 1st link (mediamatters). Watching Fox makes you less likely to be informed than watching NO NEWS AT ALL on many topics: when TARP came up for a vote most Republicans opposed it (NOT), most economists estimate the stimulus caused job losses (NOT), most economists have estimated the health care law will worsen the deficit (NOT), the stimulus legislation did not include any tax cuts (NOT), the auto bailout only occurred under Obama (NOT). Look at the other links too.

Comment: @user44212 - looks like you're way more misinformed than those stoooopid Fox News viewers: "*That same day, the legislation for the bailout was put before the United States House of Representatives and failed 205–228, with one not voting. Democrats voted 140–95 in favor of the legislation, **while Republicans voted 133–65 against it***" [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_Economic_Stabilization_Act_of_2008#First_House_vote.2C_September_29)

Comment: @user44212 - Stimulus causing job losses - WAY more complicated than you present. Most of the studies that are any good did NOT take into account the fact that stimulus spending raised taxes and/or deficit. They merely measured whether stimulus money had stimulative effect >1. Which means that if you look at ALL the real world effects of stimulus, they don't tell you if there was an AGGREGATE job loss from that money being unavailable to taxed private sector to create jobs. Of course, like most people disliking fox, you think moneyt grows on trees.

Comment: @user44212 -  "most economists have estimated the health care law will worsen the deficit" - **[proven false by now](http://www.thefiscaltimes.com/Articles/2014/06/05/CBO-Quietly-Drops-Forecast-Obamacare-Will-Cut-Deficit)** - CBO stopped projecting that now that reality caught up with fantasy.

Comment: "the auto bailout only occurred under Obama" - On one hand, yes, Bush did. OTOH, [the left wing media was the one who tried to attribute auto bailout to Obama only](http://www.newyorker.com/news/john-cassidy/an-inconvenient-truth-it-was-george-w-bush-who-bailed-out-the-automakers). So the causality is highly disputable here

Comment: First of all, I was quoting multiple studies, not my opinions. Second, the overall republican vote with which TARP passed was 34 + 91 for vs 14 + 108 against (from that same wiki). Third, a lot more people than you think "get" deadweight loss, the multiplier, Keynes and Friedman -- a lot of us studied economics in college, but also enough social science to understand where the assumptions and simple models break down.

Comment: @user44212 - the point is, there's a significant reason for even expert disagreement, so stating that there is some "truth" consensus (that just happens to dovetail to your political preference) and that anyone non-expert who listens to and believes different experts are misinformed, is disingenuous at best. That study you linked basically cherry picked or misrepresented most of its questions as clear-cut "correct answer is X" whereas only one of those you listed (auto bailout under Bush) is anywhere near as clear-cut. You can always design any study and survey to achieve desired result.

Comment: @user44212 - Someone can spend a day and design a set of very similar questions tailored to show that MSNBC viewers are deeply mis-informed about important topics, based simply on a set of facts I observe left wing people not knowing just on this site.

Comment: "Blogs are your best bet" then stating you won't go into the reasons you believe that is simply a bad SE answer.

Comment: @DA. - the level of effort put into the question is commesurate with level of effort I put into the answer. Fair criticism on your part, of course, but I just don't want to write a dissertation on modern media for a question that will be closed.

Comment: @dvk I'll give you that!

Comment: -1 for "for a variety of reasons I won't expand into". A further -1 for spending more time insulting the questioner than providing an answer.